# No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/progresses"} missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

While trying to create my edit link for my admin dashboard.I have this error...
`No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"admin/progresses"} missing required keys: [:id]`
Could you please explain me what's wrong?

here is my `rake routes`:

```
 admin GET    /admin(.:format)                         admin/dashboard#index
         admin_progresses GET    /admin/progresses(.:format)              admin/progresses#index
                          POST   /admin/progresses(.:format)              admin/progresses#create
       new_admin_progress GET    /admin/progresses/new(.:format)          admin/progresses#new
      edit_admin_progress GET    /admin/progresses/:id/edit(.:format)     admin/progresses#edit
           admin_progress GET    /admin/progresses/:id(.:format)          admin/progresses#show
                          PATCH  /admin/progresses/:id(.:format)          admin/progresses#update
                          PUT    /admin/progresses/:id(.:format)          admin/progresses#update
                          DELETE /admin/progresses/:id(.:format)          admin/progresses#destroy
```

This is my views/admin/progresses/index.html.slim

```
.container
  .row
    h2 Pepito's Dashboard
    br
    = link_to "New article", new_admin_progress_path, class:'btn btn-success'
    br
    br
    
    .dashboard
      - @progresses.each do |progress|
        .row 

          .col-xs-2
            h4
            = progress.title.capitalize
          .col-xs-2
            h4
            = progress.date
          .col-xs-5
            h4  
            = truncate(progress.content, length: 90)
          .col-xs-1
            = link_to 'View', progresses_path, class:'btn btn-success'
          .col-xs-1
            = link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(@progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
          .col-xs-1
            = link_to 'Destroy', "#", class:'btn btn-danger', method: :delete
        hr
```

This is my admin/progresses_controller.rb:

```
  class Admin::ProgressesController < Admin::ApplicationController

    def index
      @progresses = Progress.all
    end

    def new
      @progress = Progress.new
    end

    def show
      @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])

    end

    def create
       @progress = Progress.new(progress_params)

       respond_to do |format|
         if @progress.save
           unless params[:progress_attachments].nil?
             params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
               @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
             end
           end
           format.html { redirect_to admin_progresses_path, notice: 'Progress was successfully created.' }
         else
           format.html { render action: 'new' }
         end
       end

     end

     def edit
       @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
     end

     def destroy
        @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
     end

     def update
      @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
        if @progress.update(params[:progress].permit(:title, :date, :content, :main_image, progress_attachments_attributes: [:id, :progress_id, :image]))
          redirect_to progresses_path
        else
      render 'edit'
        end
    end


     private

     def progress_params
        params.require(:progress).permit(:title, :content, :date, :main_image, progress_attachments_attributes: [:id, :progress_id, :image])
     end

  end
```

Many thanks ! :)

## Edit

Thanks everyone for all the answers!

`= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'` worked well !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(@progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

to

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

The variable you want to use is not an instance variable, it's the local variable from

```
@progresses.each do |progress|
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `@progress` to `progress`

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

As you are displaying the `edit` link inside a loop, you don't have `@progress` available but `progress`

Answer (score 0):

Since you're looping through `@progresses` with the local variable `progress`, you should pass in `progress` to the url helper.

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(@progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

should be

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
edit_admin_progress_path(progress)
```

`@progress` is instance variable and it is just `nil` without any error if unset

Answer (score 0):

Try dropping the '@' before `progress` in your edit path - in the form builder you are using `progress` to take place of each individual progress in `@progresses`, so you don't need to refer to the instance `@progress` in that particular path:

```
link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
```

Additionally, `@progress` isn't set in your index view, which this form is part of. You do however set `@progress` in your edit view, but that's once you follow the link and make the `get` request.

Please let me know if that doesn't work!